# Can I create an x86 Silverlight browser application?

Tags: c#, silverlight

I made a default Silverlight 5 project in VS2013 and let Visual Sudio create the sample web host as a web application. I then ran it and saw that it loaded fine.
Now things get odd: I want to call some C++ code (cryptopp) so I think that I need Silverlight to run as x86 to include it. When I swap it to build as x86 and run the app in the browser it crashes (not calling anything yet, *only* swapping the debug build configuration to x86).

So: Is it even possible to run Silverlight as x86?

Edit:
64 bit OS.  32bit and 64bit IE both fail to display

Comment: Also repro'd in Win7 64bit building a Silverlight 4 application as x86 in VS2010.  That one fails to load, as well.

Comment: For what it is worth, I was able to call into Kernel32.dll with no issues in Any Cpu and elevated permissions... just can't get it to run at all in x86

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is apparently no. 
No you cannot run a Silverlight app that has been compiled as x86.  It fails to initialize.

It appears to have a hard time loading an assembly that is required for a base, empty Silverlight app. We've verified it on 3 machines in both Silverlight 4 and 5.

Answer (score 1):

Your only chance to [call a lib written in C++](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh560563%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) (and therefore unmanaged code) is to run your silverlight app with [elevated trust](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721083%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).
You did not mention that you configured it to require elevated trust, so maybe that's where your actual problem lies? I don't think it has anything to do with x86 vs x64.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Without attempting to pinvoke anything I get an error.  All I do is make a new Silverlight app, then swap it to x86, and then hit F5.  When I was attempting pinvoke I did run in elevated trust.